# Nullable int Culture Specific toString()

Tags: c#, int, tostring, long-integer, cultureinfo

I have int and nullable int variables that I want to convert to string using a specific culture format, namely to separate the number with dots.

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
int contactSum = 123456;
int? resultSum = 654321;
```

For the int I can do the following:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The contact sum was: {contactSum.ToString("N0", culture)}");
```

This will output the following

> The contact sum was: 123.456

Nullable int however has no overloads for formatting. How can I format the nullable int the same way as the int? Or is there a better way to do this type of formatting?

The end result would be the following:

> The result sum was: 654.321

Comment: `resultSum?.ToString` would work, *if* you're content with an empty string if you have no value. (That's also why it won't just work out of the box: you have to make a decision on what should be done with `null`, and once you've tested for that `.Value` will be yours to do with as you please.)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. That's just what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the two different ways you could achieve your goal.

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
int contactSum = 123456;
int? resultSum = 654321;
Console.WriteLine($"The contact sum was: {contactSum.ToString("N0", culture)}");
Console.WriteLine($"The contact sum was: {resultSum?.ToString("N0", culture)}");
Console.WriteLine($"The contact sum was: {(resultSum.HasValue ? resultSum.Value.ToString("N0", culture) : "NULL")}");
```

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant way of writing this:

1. Specifiy the format to use as part of the placeholder
2. Store the interpolated string literal as `FormattableString` and then use `ToString()` on the whole string to specify which culture to use when interpreting it.

Sample code

```
private void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int contactSum = 123456;
    int? resultSum = 654321;
    int? nullSum = null;

    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

    ShowInt(contactSum, culture);
    ShowInt(resultSum, culture);
    ShowInt(nullSum, culture);

    culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");

    ShowInt(contactSum, culture);
    ShowInt(resultSum, culture);
    ShowInt(nullSum, culture);
}

private void ShowInt(int? value, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
{
    FormattableString message = $"The Sum was: {value:N0}";
    Console.WriteLine(message.ToString(formatProvider));
}
```

Output:

> ```
> The Sum was: 123,456
> The Sum was: 654,321
> The Sum was: 
> The Sum was: 123.456
> The Sum was: 654.321
> The Sum was:
> ```